# How to disable customer registration?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, customer, magento-community

How can I disable customer registration via website. But the admin is capable of inserting new users via the admin panel?

Comment: You can use below paid extension. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/medma-disable-customer-registration.html using this.

Answer (score 2):

Admin -> System -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Website Restrictions.

Comment: I can't find that option. Where is it ?

Comment: My apologies it appears this is only in Enterprise.

Comment: This functionality is actually for limiting access to website only for logged in users - not for disabling registration.